# Premiere Pro - Copies vs Instances of Graphics

Tags: premiere, editing, premiere-pro

I'm trying to finally transition away from Premiere Pro's Legacy Titles, but I'm having trouble getting used to the "Essential Graphics".

In general I find it confusing that Graphics behave differently than clips, and my main questions at the moment are:

- Where can I get an overview of all graphics used in a Project ? The Graphics I've created are not in the Project panel. (But the "Upgraded" graphics Premiere creates automatically, are there!)
- How can I create *a second instance* of a Graphic, so that if I edit one instance, all the instances will be modified? If I `Alt-Drag` a graphic in the timeline, this will create an *independent copy*, i.e. that will be edited independently from the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, wrapping up [a thread from the Adobe Community](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/copies-vs-instances-of-graphics/m-p/12747302):

- All Graphics used in the active sequence will be visible in the "Text" panel/window, under "Graphics".
- If you create a Graphic from scratch, it won't be visible in the Project panel, and if you Alt-drag, this will create an independent copy in the timeline.
- Once a graphic is selected, from the "Graphics and Titles" menu, you can "**Convert to Source Graphics**". This will add the item to the Project Bin, and you can use the same graphic several times

From the [Premiere Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/upgrade-legacy-titles.html):

> Source Graphics are modern essential graphics that work in a similar
> way to Legacy Titles:
>
> - They have a project item.
> - You can track usage through the metadata column for Video Usage.
> - Edits made to the project item or an associated track item will ripple through all track items.

- Note that if you Alt-drag a Source Graphics, it will be duplicated, creating a new copy of it in the Project Panel.